# EntityFramework.Extended not working on my project

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I installed `EntityFramework.Extended` however i cannot get it to work. i am using linq to entities and i imported the namespace.

```
using EntityFramework.Extensions;

var context = new DataSources.sspEntities();
context.Payroll_Details.Delete(u => u.FirstName == "firstname");
```

the .Delete does not come up. Instead i get delete objects. Am i missing something? I was able to successfully download and install the package. I would like to do bulk delete using the entityframe.extension

Comment: What do you mean by "I get delete objects"?

Comment: I wonder if this is about EntityFramework.Extended or about what base class you use for your context. If your context is derived from `DbContext` your entity sets will be of `DbSet<T>` type and you will get `.Delete`. On the other hand if your context is derived from `ObjectContext` your entity sets will be `ObjectSet`s which will have `Delete` method (and not `DeleteObject` methods)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of EntityFramework are you using? I just did a small example with the EntityFramework.Extender 6.0.0.86 and with the EntityFramework 6.0.2 and it works perfect.

Also, the type of the entity class in which I'm able to see the Delete function is System.Data.Entity.DbSet .